# Rviz says no transform found even though transform is being published

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add a `RobotModel plugin` in the `Rviz Display`.

When I add the `RobotModel plugin`, I get the following error -

[image: image description]

However, all the transforms are being published on my `tf` tree. This is how my `tf` tree looks -

[image: image description]

Why is this happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371244/rviz-says-no-transform-found-even-though-transform-is-being-published/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz is correct.

You haven't configured the *TF Prefix* property of the *RobotModel* display correctly: it's empty, but it should be set to `husky_1`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-07**:
Seems this was marked as *offensive*. Would be nice to know why.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-07**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-07**:\

> @gvdhoorn you mean this question was marked as offensive?

no, my answer was marked as offensive.

I don't understand why, hence my comment to ask for clarification.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-08**:
Oh okay.
Got it.